# Circle doesn't change color when active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make the menu items change color when the user interacts with them.

Currently the color of the circle and the text change, but when the item is active, the text color changes but not the circle.

In my HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid hidden-xs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div id="sous_menu_1" class="row">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="row">
                <ul class="ul_1">
                  <li><a id="about">à propos</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a>poles</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a>clients</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="row">
                <ul class="ul_2">
                  <li><a>projets</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a>carriere</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a>contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div id="sous_menu_2" class="row">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS:

```css
.ul_1,
.ul_2 {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.ul_1 {
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.ul_2 {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.ul_1 li,
.ul_2 li {
  position: relative;
}
.ul_1 a,
.ul_2 a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}
.ul_1 a {
  text-align: right;
}
.ul_2 a {
  text-align: left;
}
.ul_1 li::after {
  background-color: #bcbec0;
  border: 1px solid #bcbec0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: -15px;
  content: " ";
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 6px;
}
.ul_2 li::before {
  background-color: #bcbec0;
  border: 1px solid #bcbec0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -15px;
  content: " ";
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 6px;
}
.active::after {
  background-color: #ED008C !important;
}
.ul_1 li:hover::after {
  background-color: #ED008C !important;
}
.ul_1 li a .active::after {
  background-color: #ED008C !important;
}
```

On the active page a class is added via JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#about').addClass('active');
});
```

I thought this would do the trick but no:

```css
.ul_1 li a .active::after{
    background-color: #ED008C !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually trying to target the wrong pseudo-element.

You're defining the pseudo-element as:

```
.ul_1 li::after {
    background-color: #bcbec0;
    border: 1px solid #bcbec0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: -15px;
    content: " ";
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

Instead of

```
.ul_1 li a::after {
    background-color: #bcbec0;
    border: 1px solid #bcbec0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: -15px;
    content: " ";
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

So when the `active` class is applied to the anchor link it won't work because your selector is wrong.

```
.ul_1 li a.active::after {
  background-color: #ED008C;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#about').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.ul_1,
.ul_2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.ul_1 {
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.ul_2 {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.ul_1 li,
.ul_2 li {
  position: relative;
}
.ul_1 a,
.ul_2 a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}
.ul_1 a {
  text-align: right;
}
.ul_2 a {
  text-align: left;
}
.ul_1 li a::after {
  background-color: #bcbec0;
  border: 1px solid #bcbec0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: -15px;
  content: " ";
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 6px;
}
.ul_2 li::before {
  background-color: #bcbec0;
  border: 1px solid #bcbec0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -15px;
  content: " ";
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 6px;
}
.active::after {
  background-color: #ED008C;
}
.ul_1 li:hover::after {
  background-color: #ED008C;
}
.ul_1 li a.active::after {
  background-color: #ED008C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid hidden-xs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div id="sous_menu_1" class="row">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="row">
                <ul class="ul_1">
                  <li><a id="about">à propos</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a>poles</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a>clients</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

So, correct the original definition and it works!